# Angular 2 Parent component initiates/Oninit called again on child route change

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-components, angular-module

I am using a module to be loaded by default as in our app route module configuration:

```
     [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'accounts', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'accounts', loadChildren: './accounts/accounts.module#AccountsModule'},
      { path: 'report', component: PageNotFoundComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

And below is my route configuration for account Module :

```
 [{ path: 'accounts', component: AccountsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService], canActivateChild: [AuthGuardService], children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'search', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent, pathMatch: 'full',data: { reuse: true } },
      {path: 'docDetails/:id', component: DocDetailComponent,children: [
              { path: '', redirectTo: 'overview', pathMatch: 'full' },
              { path: 'overview', component: OverviewComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
              { path: 'update', component: UpdateComponent }
            ] }
      ] }
  ];
```

In my Account Component Template `accounts.component.html` i have added a module to be loaded by default and have provided a router-outlet like below :

```
<navbar><navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Issue is that on every child route change accounts component `oninit` function is called again, as well as constructor get created again.

> Say i move from `accounts/search` to `/accounts/docDetails/12` , the accounts component gets initiated once again. I do not have any requirement with lazy loading of module, I can even use eager load, so either of them will work for me. Its just that according to angular docs i couldn't find any other way to load modules.

Comment: did you find a solution?